# MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED Reason Code 2035

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have set up a MQ Server 7.1 on my local machine.

I have set up a Queue Manager : **QM_APPLE**

I am trying to run the sample .Net Code from the MQ Examples to PUT a message on the Queue : **Q1**.

When I try to instantiate the MQQueueManager, I get the above error.

I have tried following the Authorization steps in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21166937 but I am still getting the error. Obviously I am not specifying the parameters correctly here. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is the cmd line I am trying to use : setmqaut -m QM_APPLE -t qmgr -p greg@xyz-think +alladm   ..... where I am the administrator on the machine name xyz-think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alladm is administrative privileges. It doesn't work for API privileges. Try with +allmqi.
But that's generally not advisable.  Try to drill down to specific authorization (like put, get, setid, setall) when you start developing a real application.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc%2Fq083500_.htm

Comment: I have trawled that page for hours and tried scores of other IBM authored "fixes". Nothing works. I have tried with your suggestion and it doesn't work. The error is still being thrown. The setmqaut tells me the command executed successfully but the error persists. There was another IBM "fix" that said the server administrator couldnt be the admin for a queue manager. Crazy but true. I added a new user to mqm group. Didnt work. Tried doing a get on the message. Didnt work. How can I drill down? Why can a message just be given saying what object needs permission. The logs are just as useless...

Comment: First create a normal (non mqm user) and give permissions.  mqm and members of mqm are specifically blocked from MQ 7.1 onwards. The easiest and most unsecure way is to switch off these if you are frustrated at this point. Using the MQExplorer, connect to the local qmgr, right click to get properties, select communication, set channel authentication records to disabled. If you are not even able to connect through MQ Explorer, open a command prompt, type runmqsc QM_APPLE. This should bring the console. type ALTER CHLAUTH(DISABLED). This should allow you to connect.

Comment: Ah well my joy was short lived. Next error is MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME .. straight out of the IBM sample code. Unbelievable.

Comment: Whatever queue used by the sample code or passed as arguments to the sample code must be created in the qmgr and given permissions to access (at this stage allmqi even though I dont advise). If this is completely new and if you are not required to use MQ 7.1, I suggest go for MQ 7.5. This version has much better error reporting in the error logs (AMERR01.LOG found inside the installation folder)

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I have to use 7.1. Ok - Its all working now. I can write and read messages. Its a POC so I will delegate the heavy lifting admin stuff to the MQ Admin.